# Using vector values in data retrieval

Tags: c++, vector

I'm trying to use vectors within a vector call. This works:

```
void calc_equipment(auto &gamedata, auto &player)
{

player.equipment.STR += gamedata.items[gamedata.equipment[player.total.id].weapon.STR;
player.equipment.STR += gamedata.items[gamedata.equipment[player.total.id].armor.STR;

}
```

But this does not:

```
void calc_equipment(auto &gamedata, auto &player)
{

vector<string> types;
types.resize(2);
types[0] = "weapon";
types[1] = "armor";


player.equipment.STR += gamedata.items[gamedata.equipment[player.total.id].types[0].STR;
player.equipment.STR += gamedata.items[gamedata.equipment[player.total.id].types[1].STR;

}
```

Obviously it doesn't work that way, but could someone point me in the right direction? How do I structure and use types[] to retrieve the correct data? I could use integers instead of strings, but it doesn't work either. The end goal is to iterate these calculations instead of writing them out manually.

Cheers!

Comment: `std::string` has no  `STR` member.

Comment: `auto` is not allowed in function prototype (yet)

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. What types are `gamedata` and `player`?

Comment: I'm trying to load these calculations dynamcally with a vector of {weapon,armor}

Comment: If this is the way that people are going to try to use `auto`, I shudder for the future of the language.

Comment: Your brackets don't match.

Answer (score 0):

Your example is [much more complicated than it had to be](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but you seem to want to manipulate variables by means of strings containing their names. I don't remember the name of this approach, but C++ does not support it.

I think the best approach (if you really want to do this) would be a wrapper that makes the members of the structure available by means of the index operator.

```
class EquipmentWrapper
{
public:
  EquipmentWrapper(Equipment &nE): E(nE)
  {}

  int operator[](unsigned int k) const
  {
    switch(k)
      {
      case 0: return E.weapon;
      case 1: return E.armor;
      default: throw(0);
    }
  }

private:
  Equipment &E;
};

...
EquipmentWrapper W(gamedata.equipment[player.total.id]);
player.equipment.STR += W[0].STR;
player.equipment.STR += W[1].STR;
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to iterate the fields of a struct in a reflective manner. There's no built-in support as Beta mentioned.

You could overload streaming operators for your item types, and for a generic collection of items called equipment. Each struct knows how to stringify itself. Your client code just asks the top-level equipment to insert itself into a stream. Example below:

```
using namespace std;

struct Weapon
{
    Weapon(string const & nm) : name(nm) {}
    string name;  
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream & os, Weapon const & w)
{
    os << w.name;
    return os;
}

struct Armor
{
    Armor(string const & nm) : name(nm) {}
    string name;
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream & os, Armor const & a)
{
    os << a.name;
    return os;
}

struct Equipment
{
    Equipment(Weapon const & _w, Armor const & _a) : w(_w), a(_a) {}
    Weapon w;
    Armor a;
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream & os, Equipment const & e)
{
    os << e.w << ", " << e.a;
    return os;
}

int main()
{
  Weapon w("sword of smiting");
  Armor a("plate of deflection");
  Equipment e(w, a);

  //can be sstream just as well to collect into a string
  cout << e << endl;
}
```